# How do you apply limits and ordering to associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a query that can do the following,

`Category` has_many `Dates`

- Query takes a location and a category
- Provides an array of categories, ordered by the number of jobs in the category. For this, I'm using `default_scope { order(jobs_count: :desc) }` in the `Category` model, where jobs_count is a counter.

In each category the query provides an array of jobs

- Jobs are ordered by the boolean associated attribute `order.featured`, then by date (`order` belongs_to `job`)
- Only shows jobs with the attribute: `open: true`. This can be done with a scope.
- Only shows jobs near location if a location is present. This requires a call of the Class method Job.within()
- Shows only 20 if no category has been set. This is proving really difficult.

Is this possible in 3 calls to the database?

**Attempt at a solution**

At a high level, I first find the find the jobs in the right area, with the attribute `open: true`

If I need to show only 20 jobs per category, I group the jobs by category using ruby's `group_by`, attempt to order them correctly, then remove all but the first 20 in each array.

I take the IDs of these jobs.

I perform a database call to the Category table, with `Category.includes(:jobs).where(jobs: { id: job_ids})`. Default scopes ensure the order is correct.

However, I'm getting stuck at the final obstacle! I can't seem to order the jobs that come back this way. The default_scope seems to be being ignored, and I don't know how to apply an order or a scope to the jobs called in the `Category` query.

Is this the correct way to approach the problem? Is there an easier way? Would Jobs.group_by(...) be better - it seems to require passing in raw SQL in the ruby docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group